# How many records can a maximally full B+ Tree with d = 3 and height = 3 hold?

Tags: database, b-tree, database-indexes

How many records can a maximally full B+ Tree with d = 3 and height = 3 hold?

From my point, it's either `7^3 * 6`(only one node in root) or `7 ^ 4 + 6` (all node in root node is full)

However, the autograder told it's not correct but doesn't give me the correct answer, wondering if I misunderstand anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to know how calculate this question.

In my opinion, this is`7^3 * 6`.

`(2d + 1)^height * 2d`

Answer (score 0):

B+ tree leaf node stores data, so for a height of 3 B+ tree, the total records ( that stores at the leaf level) should be `(2d + 1)^H *(2d)= (2*3+1)^(height-1)*(6) = 7^2*6 = 294`

The actual height H should exclude leaf level.